# Mac computer on a plane

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

Im traveling from NY to Toronto on a plane. Can I take a desk iMac computer in the checked luggage without the risk of mess up the computer because of the heat or coldness of the cargo of the aircraft?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is properly wrapped and packed, it should be OK.

The problem is not the temperature, but the handling by airport staff.

Stick on the box/luggage, "fragile" stickers.

Also, check if you have insurance for damage baggage.

Comment: There’s quite a bit of debate on the effectiveness of “fragile” stickers. Most people think this will just make the check-in agent make you sign a liability waiver and it will have no effect on handling. So you’d better protect you iMac very well. Don’t forget your bag may end up at the bottom of a pile, with lots of very heavy luggage thrown onto it multiple times.